# Двоеточие или двоеточие с кавычками?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, двоеточие

Можно ли поставить двоеточие в этом предложении?
**Не зря же говорят: наглость — второе счастье.**
Запятую можно поставить точно, потому что "не зря говорят" можно посчитать вводной конструкцией. А вот можно ли двоеточие ставить или даже двоеточие с кавычками?

Answer (score 1):

Вот что рекомендуется в справочнике под редакцией В. В. Лопатина (§136).

> Прямая речь не выделяется кавычками:
>   а) если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит (прямая речь вводится безличным или неопределенно-личным предложением): *Не даром говорится: дело мастера боится* (посл.); *Про него говорили: строгий, но справедливый*...

[Знаки препинания при прямой речи](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85/)

*Не зря же говорят* — неопределенно-личное предложение. После него ставим двоеточие. Кавычки не нужны.

Не зря в народе говорят: наглость — второе счастье (АиФ).

Как выяснилось, скромность у Хани отсутствовала напрочь, но не зря же говорят: наглость — второе счастье (А. и Ж. Богдановы).

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе такие рассуждения:

***Не зря же говорят, что наглость - второе счастье.***

Сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, которое является косвенной речью (передача чужого высказывания придаточным предложением).

Выкидываем союз **что** и получаем:

***Не зря говорят: наглость - второе  счастье.***

То же самое по смыслу, что и выше, однако без союза. Бессоюзное сложно предложение это. Но уже можно говорить тут о прямой речи.

Есть правило (не то чтобы правило, а закономерность и рекомендация):

> 2. Не выделяется кавычками прямая речь в следующих случаях:
>
> 1) если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит, или если
>   приводится общеизвестная пословица, поговорка:
>
> Про Ивашку Бровкина говорили: крепкий (А. Т.); Дома и хворать легче и
>   жить дешевле; и недаром говорится: дома и стены помогают (Ч.).

Можешь следовать ему.

Сравни:

1. Недаром говорится: дома и стены помогают
2. Не зря говорят: наглость - второе  счастье

Ну одно и то же.

Финальный ответ:

**Не зря говорят: наглость второе  счастье** - писать так точно не будет ошибкой.